# How to find the count of records based on multiple column values in single table SQL

Tags: sql

```
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| ID | Country CodeR | CountryCodeB | CountryCodeBR | CountryCodeF |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|  1 | US            | US           | US            | UK           |
|  2 | US            | UK           | US            | PK           |
|  3 | US            | UK           | PK            | IND          |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

I would like to count the number of rows in this table where there are at least three distinct country codes.

In this example, for ID = 1 there are only two distinct country code, but for ID = 2 and 3 there are 3 (US, UK, PK) and 4 (US, UK, PK, IND), respectively, distinct country codes. Hence, the result should be 2

How can I get this . any suggestions. thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Sorry, can you post in question also, what do you expect as the result of SQL on this table to be? I do not understand the first sentence of your question.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Whati is 3? and what is 2? can you ellaborate?

Comment: @Gnudiff  , sorry for my poor English. I have above table , from above table I want record count which are having three distinct country codes out of four country code columns. hop u guys got my question

Comment: @JajulaSiva It's ok now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If want have at least 3 diferent mean only one can be equal,  so

```
 X  - Y  - Z  - {X,Y,Z}
```

So to get rows with only one duplicate you do

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  -- or * for debug
FROM yourTable
WHERE 1 - (CASE WHEN CountryCodeR  = CountryCodeB  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
        - (CASE WHEN CountryCodeR  = CountryCodeBR THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
        - (CASE WHEN CountryCodeR  = CountryCodeF  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
        - (CASE WHEN CountryCodeB  = CountryCodeBR THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
        - (CASE WHEN CountryCodeB  = CountryCodeF  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
        - (CASE WHEN CountryCodeBR = CountryCodeF  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) >= 0
```

If you have more than one duplicated the total will be less than 0.

Comment: From the above query It has performance issue . Is there any we can achieve using self join?

Comment: Explain why is a performance issue? How many rows? A self join will be also big. You can UNPIVOT the table but you didnt specify your RDBMS

Comment: +1 for elegant solution. My initial thought was about concatenating columns and applying regexp with counting matches. Note that if this is MySQL, you need to use "END" at the end of each case.

Comment: If you need it to go faster, perhaps you need to create indexes on columns in WHERE clause.

Comment: @Gnudiff actually I think you need `END` every db using `CASE`. I  just missed.

Comment: @Gnudiff one index wont help, because you are doing a calculation. You will need a `FULL TABLE SCAN`